# Find text and numbers Formatted: "Case: BE########" and format them, regardless of the number

Tags: vba, text, ms-word, reformatting

I need to reformat hundreds of case numbers in a Word document.
They all start with "Case: BE:" followed by eight numbers.
I need to find ALL of the "Case: BE########" and get it to bold and underline each of them.

I tried recording a macro [because that's how I usually figure it out] But when I do that, I need to search for a particular case number because I don't know how to represent ANY number in the search string. When I search for and find one case number, it will only do one thing at a time, bold or underline.  And the case number I searched for doesn't even show up in the macro.

Comment: In Advanced Find window Find what: `Case: BE([0-9]{8})`

Comment: See https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Case: BE` is a literal string.
- `[0-9]` matches any digit from 0 to 9.
- `{8}` specifies that the preceding character (in this case, digits) should be repeated exactly 8 times.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Find.Execute method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.execute?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm162529724)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Replacement.ClearFormatting method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.replacement.clearformatting?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm162594836)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Selection.Find property (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.find?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158662918)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub BoldAndUnderline()
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "Case: BE[0-9]{8}"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        With .Replacement.Font
            .Bold = True
            .Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        End With
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```